# Python Postgres multiple delete

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, sql-delete, postgresql-9.4

Want to delete data from multiple tables.
As i understood, there is no way to do it via join/using in Postresql (currently 9.4). It is possible to delete only from one table at a time.
Trying like this, but data was deleted only from t1, obviously. Maybe there is a mistake in my query.

```
DELETE FROM 
    shema.table1 t1
USING
    shema.table2 t2,
    shema.table3 t3,
    shema.table4 t4
WHERE 
    t1.id = 111 AND
    t1.id = t2.t1_id AND
    t2.id = t3.t2_id AND
    t2.id = t4.t2_id
```

---

**Question 1.**
There is no simple way to delete data from multiple tables in one query with some feature like join in Postgresql?

**Question 2.**
Query/ies is suppose to be run in python with sqlalchemy as raw SQL statements.
Is there a difference how multiple *DELETE* statements will be execute?

As separate queries.
Probably execute all queries within transaction.

```
from sqlalchemy import text

query_1 = text('DELETE ...')
query_2 = text('DELETE ...')
query_3 = text('DELETE ...')

engine.execute(query_1)
engine.execute(query_2)
engine.execute(query_3)
```

Or as one long statement

```
from sqlalchemy import text

queries = text(
    'DELETE ...;'
    'DELETE ...;'
    'DELETE ...;'
)

engine.execute(queries)
```

Comment: If you want to delete from multiple tables, you need to run multiple DELETE statements

Comment: 1) Postgres 9.4 is coming up on 3 years past EOL, you should be thinking of moving on. 2) Do the tables have `FOREIGN KEY` relationships?

Comment: 1) sadly, i have no opportunity to change versions.
2) no, they don't.

It seems that i have to use multiple delete queries